# Map not updating rendered stateful child Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the following to spread Map values inside a stack. All widgets are positioned.

```
...widgets.values,
```

This works fine, however when I used the Map.update function to update the position of the Widgets at a certain key, there is no change to the widgets position.

```
if (widgets.containsKey(uniqueValue)) {
          setState(() {
            widgets.update(
              uniqueValue,
              (value) => Box(
                uuid: uniqueValue,
                startPosLeft: newPos,
                startPostop: newPos,
                onMoved: (uniqueValue) => _boxMoved(uniqueValue),
              ),
            );
          });
```

I can see the widget is being updated if I print out the Map Widget position, but it wont move.

Any idea what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the state not being updated inside the child widget.

My solution was to create a behavioral subject with RXDart and bind the stream listen function in the widgets initState function.

**Bloc Class**

```
  final boxMovementController = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  Function(List<String>) get inputMovingBoxId =>
      boxMovementController.sink.add;
```

**Child Widget**

```
streamSubscription = bloc.boxMovementController.listen((value) {
      setState(() {});
    });
```

The widget would then call setState whenever it detected an addition to the behavioral Subject stream.

The parent would then sink.add to the stream whenever positioned changed therefore triggering a state update on the child.

**Parent Widget**

```
bloc.boxMovementController(value);
```

Hopefully this is useful to others facing a similar issue.